# Where to put commonly used Screen in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When we are using Instagram or Facebook, we can open Post Detail page from anywhere such as Feed, Profile, PhotoPage.

Where do we put commonly-used screen such as Post Detail Screen in react-navigation?

Choices 2. Or could you give me any example?

1) Should I copy and paste PostDetail Screen to all tabs?

2) or should I make another Screen inside of TabNavigator?

Here is my TabNavigator and also Root Navigator.

```
export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: FeedScreen,
    },
    Camera: {
      screen: CameraScreen,
    },
    Noti: {
      screen: NotificationScreen,
    },
    Menu: {
      screen: MenuStackNavigator,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I just added the screen that is used by 3 StackNavigators to the declaration (RouteConfig) of each StackNavigator.

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen